Excel: find position of character with specific format in a cell
I have a column of cells with text which I want to sort alphabetically. But not all cells should be sorted by their first characters. In these cells the character by which they should be sorted is formatted with a (single) underline.
Now I want to create an auxiliary column which contains only

for strings that have at least one char underlined: the (rest of the) string, from the underlined character
for strings without underlined char: the full string

Example columns

I got some VBA code together which looks reasonable to me:
Function GetUnderlinedText(inputText As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim underlinedCharIndex As Long
    Dim underlinedText As String

    ' Get the reference to the cell
    Set cell = Application.Caller

    ' Find the index of the first underlined character
    underlinedCharIndex = FindUnderlinedChar(inputText)

    ' If underlined character found, return the portion of text starting from that character
    If underlinedCharIndex > 0 Then
        underlinedText = Mid(inputText, underlinedCharIndex)
    Else
        underlinedText = inputText
    End If

    ' Return the underlined portion of the text
    GetUnderlinedText = underlinedText
End Function

Function FindUnderlinedChar(inputText As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim char As String

    ' Iterate through each character of the text
    For i = 1 To Len(inputText)
        char = Mid(inputText, i, 1)
        ' Check if the character is underlined
        If IsUnderlined(inputText, i) Then
            ' Return the index of the underlined character
            FindUnderlinedChar = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    ' If no underlined character found, return 0
    FindUnderlinedChar = 0
End Function

Function IsUnderlined(inputText As String, position As Long) As Boolean
    ' Check if the character at the specified position is underlined
    If Range("A1").Characters(position, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then
        IsUnderlined = True
    Else
        IsUnderlined = False
    End If
End Function


Where I am stuck now is the Function IsUnderlined, which always returns TRUE.
In the debugger I can verify that Range("A1").Characters(position, 1).Font.Underlinenever changes its value of -4142 (= xlUnderlineStyleNone), even as I iterate through the characters.
Can anyone help what is wrong here?

A String doesn't have formatting, btw, so you'll never be able to determine an underline from inputText. I can't repro your issue with Range("A1").Characters(position, 1).Font.Underline though: https://i.sstatic.net/KT0Bd.png

Range("A1").Characters(position, 1).Font.Underline check the underline on Cell A1. So it alway returns xlUnderlineStyleNone.

Here's one approach:
Function TextToSort(c As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, pos As Long, txt
    txt = c.Value
    Select Case Nz(c.Font.Underline, "Null")
        Case -4142, 2             'all or no underlining
            TextToSort = txt
        Case "Null"               'only some characters underlined
            For i = 1 To Len(txt) 'get first underline position
                If c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = 2 Then
                    pos = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            TextToSort = Mid(txt, pos, Len(txt))
    End Select
End Function

'return `ifNull` is v is null, otherwise return v
Function Nz(v, ifNull)
    Nz = IIf(IsNull(v), ifNull, v)
End Function


Much more concise than ChatGPT

@BigBen - always my aim!   Not redundant just yet...

Thanks a lot for the prompt and concise solution. Gave me a good lesson :-) One major point I was missing, and would like to understand in more detail: Obviously c.Font.Underline i. e. the cell content can have a value of "Null" if only parts of it are underlined/formatted. Could you refer me to a documentation, where I find more about possible values ? So far I only found the enums for the ..underlineStyle.., but indeed this only makes sense either for individual characters or the full cell content - but nothing "in between" (part of the cell).

I'm only aware of On/Off and Null (note not the string "Null" - I just did that for the Select Case)


Regardless of where the formula is located, the IsUnderlined function always checks the format of cell A1 with the following code. Therefore, the return values are always the same.

If Range("A1").Characters(position, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then


Use a range object as argument
Add an If clause to enhance the code. Underline returns Null if part of conents are with underline.

 inputText.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle ' all chars with underline
 inputText.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone ' no underline in cell

Option Explicit
Function GetUnderlinedText(inputText As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim underlinedCharIndex As Long
    Dim underlinedText As String
    
    If inputText.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle Or inputText.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone Then
        GetUnderlinedText = inputText.Value
    Else
        ' Find the index of the first underlined character
        underlinedCharIndex = FindUnderlinedChar(inputText)
        
        ' If underlined character found, return the portion of text starting from that character
        If underlinedCharIndex > 0 Then
            underlinedText = Mid(inputText, underlinedCharIndex)
        Else
            underlinedText = inputText
        End If
        
        ' Return the underlined portion of the text
        GetUnderlinedText = underlinedText
    End If
    
End Function

Function FindUnderlinedChar(inputText As Range) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim char As String

    ' Iterate through each character of the text
    For i = 1 To Len(inputText.Value)
'        char = Mid(inputText, i, 1)
        ' Check if the character is underlined
        If IsUnderlined(inputText, i) Then
            ' Return the index of the underlined character
            FindUnderlinedChar = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    ' If no underlined character found, return 0
    FindUnderlinedChar = 0
End Function

Function IsUnderlined(inputText As Range, position As Long) As Boolean
    ' Check if the character at the specified position is underlined
    IsUnderlined = (inputText.Characters(position, 1).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle)
End Function



Thanks for the prompt reply and solution!
